# Explain TFX Metadata Store data model definitions

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

## GOAL

1. Explain the following definitions in plane simple english?
2. Many practical examples of what they can have?
3. What each of them do?

## ORIGINAL

This is the original https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/mlmd#data_model that I have issues with. In my description I will point back to this. “The Metadata Store uses the following data model to record and retrieve metadata from the storage backend.”:

- ArtifactTypedescribes an artifact's type and its properties that are stored in the metadata store. You can register these types on-the-fly with the metadata store in code, or you can load them in the store from a serialized format. Once you register a type, its definition is available throughout the lifetime of the store.
- An Artifactdescribes a specific instance of an ArtifactType, and its properties that are written to the metadata store.
- An ExecutionTypedescribes a type of component or step in a workflow, and its runtime parameters.
- An Executionis a record of a component run or a step in an ML workflow and the runtime parameters. An execution can be thought of as an instance of an ExecutionType. Executions are recorded when you run an ML pipeline or step.
- An Eventis a record of the relationship between artifacts and executions. When an execution happens, events record every artifact that was used by the execution, and every artifact that was produced. These records allow for lineage tracking throughout a workflow. By looking at all events, MLMD knows what executions happened and what artifacts were created as a result. MLMD can then recurse back from any artifact to all of its upstream inputs.
- A ContextTypedescribes a type of conceptual group of artifacts and executions in a workflow, and its structural properties. For example: projects, pipeline runs, experiments, owners etc.
- A Contextis an instance of a ContextType. It captures the shared information within the group. For example: project name, changelist commit id, experiment annotations etc. It has a user-defined unique name within its ContextType.
- An Attributionis a record of the relationship between artifacts and contexts.
- An Associationis a record of the relationship between executions and contexts.

## How I see them

### (Please correct my descriptions or let me know if they are right)

- Def ArtifactType (how I can draw down based on the documentations):

  - Contains the base data
  - Contains many iteration and multiple modified version of the base data
  - Defines the datatypes
  - Have properties
  - Sores data as metadata in metadata storage ex.: database, in ram.
- 1 Artifact  (how I can draw down based on the documentations):

  - 1 version of the modified data
  - 1 version of the modified data's properties
  - 1 version of the modified data's data types
  - 1 version of a specific instance of an ArtifactType, and its properties that are written to the metadata store.
  - !! BUT THAN "List all Artifacts of a specific type. Example: all Models that have been trained." [https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/mlmd#mlmd_functionality](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/mlmd#mlmd_functionality%C2%A0)  -> So saved down model can also be Artifacts. This documentation is just terrible their ArtifactType and Artifact is pointing on each other whiteout explain any of them what it is. It doesn't makes any sense.
- ExecutionType:

  - What is a "component in a workflow"?
  - What is a "step in a workflow, and its runtime parameters."
  - Because this TEXT area has NO workflow chart to point at while there is one to the previous section https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/mlmd#metadata_store and there is one after https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/mlmd#integrate_ml_metadata_into_your_ml_workflows .
- Execution:

  - What is a record here?
  - What is a  component
  - What is a component run?
  - What runtime parameters are we talking about?
  - What is Execution overall?
  - 1 version of a specific instance of ExecutionType.
  - Executions save to metadata storage (ex.: RAM or database) you run an ML pipeline or step.
- Event:

  - Is a record of the relationship between artifacts and executions.
  - to me it is not clear why is this step even necessary because event and execution sounds like they fulfill the same exact purpose.
  - to me it seems like execution saves down itself than why do we need an event to save it down again?
  - This is the only understandable statement in this definition "By looking at all events, MLMD knows what executions happened and what artifacts were created as a result."
- ContextType:

  - What is "conceptual group of artifacts and executions" ? Especially what is "conceptual" about them?
      - perfect examples this is what all the other description should be.
- Context:

  - 1 version of the ContextType.
  - Again what is this "conceptual group of artifacts and executions" ? Especially what is "conceptual" about them?
  - Again GREAT examples.
- Attribution:

  - simple and understandable description
  - If all the elements ave and describes them self why is this necessary?
- Association:

  - simple and understandable description
  - If all the elements ave and describes them self why is this necessary?

## Previous recommendations:

- Just not helpful also the colab also not answers the basic definitions - https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/mlmd/mlmd_tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific portion that you are having an issue understanding or is it more general? If it is more general, there is an excellent [tutorial notebook](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/mlmd/mlmd_tutorial) that is linked to in that website you linked.

We can also gain a more intuitive understanding of the different parts of the ML metadata from the below image, which was taken from the same link you provided.

[image: TensorFlow ML Metadata]

In the image, we see that the data and model are considered artifacts.
The Execution is that of the Trainer of the model.
Events in this flow were the input of the data and the model output while the Context annotates the entire experiment.

From here, it is easier to understand where an Attribution and Association would fit in to this scheme.

**EDIT**
To add to prior post it is best to use the following image as well from the documentation:

[image: Relationships of ML MetaData]

I am also new to TensorFlow so I am definitely with you on the documenation's lack of clarity, but I think we can look at "Artifacts" as "objects" and "executions" as a process, sort of like instructions on how to act on the artifacts. From there the "Events" can be seen merely as when data is inputted into the process and predictions are fed out, but its important to look at "Events" as just the process by which the data is read in and the predictions are read out and not the data/predictions themselves. It is rather abstract and why it took me awhile to get a grasp on it. The "Attribution" and "Association" can be thought of as the primary and foreign keys of database table in that they describe how certain items are related to each other which is why they are needed.

As for your questions on components, the [TFX User guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide) explains that:

> A TFX pipeline is a sequence of components...

So basically, "components" in TensorFlow are merely the constituent parts of the pipeline. The standard components of a TensorFlow pipeline are listed in the TFX User guide.

When it comes to workflow, I gather that its really just a generic term used to describe the end-to-end machine learning process. I believe that the term "conceptual grouping" is also generic as a ["ContextType"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/ml_metadata/api_docs/python/mlmd/proto/ContextType) is user-defined as per the API documentation. Also runtime parameters are explained in the ["Understanding TFX Pipelines"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/understanding_tfx_pipelines) documentation as:

> ...inputs to pipelines that are known before your pipeline is executed.

I believe this edit as addressed the issues you have outlined. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: It somewhat helped than it mixed up even a bit more things. I have updated my question at the bottom you find the specific questions that I have.

Comment: @sogu I have added a new section under my original answer. Hopefully this helps.